# Sudoers env_keep wildcard expression with exceptions

Tags: linux, shell, sudo

When running `sudo`, I'm trying to retain all environment variables related to the Borg backup program, with 2 exceptions.

Using `env_keep` in my sudoers config (with `env_reset` enabled), here is what I have so far:

```
Defaults env_keep += "BORG_*"

Defaults env_keep -= "BORG_CACHE_DIR BORG_SECURITY_DIR"
```

This results in all `BORG_*` variables being retained (e.g. BORG_REPO), however the variables I attempted to exclude are also retained (BORG_CACHE_DIR and BORG_SECURITY_DIR). Can anyone tell me why this doesn't work, and how to achieve what I'm trying to do?

---

#### More info

Running `sudo -l` confirms that the rules have been read:

```
Matching Defaults entries for ...:
    env_reset, mail_badpass,
    secure_path=/usr/local/sbin\:/usr/local/bin\:/usr/sbin\:/usr/bin\:/sbin\:/bin,
    passwd_timeout=2, env_keep+="SSH_CLIENT SSH_CONNECTION SSH_TTY SSH_AUTH_SOCK",
    env_keep+=BORG_*, env_keep-="BORG_CACHE_DIR BORG_SECURITY_DIR"
```

However, running `sudo -V` as root seems to confirm that my attempt at setting some exceptions to the `env_keep` rules hasn't been recognized by `sudo`:

```
...
Reset the environment to a default set of variables
Environment variables to check for safety:
    TZ
    TERM
...
Environment variables to remove:
    *=()*
    RUBYOPT
    RUBYLIB
... (nothing BORG related) ...
    IFS
Environment variables to preserve:
    BORG_*
    SSH_AUTH_SOCK
    SSH_TTY
... (nothing else BORG related) ...
```

---

#### Additional attempts

On steeldriver's suggestion in the comments of using the `!` operator, I attempted to use this line in sudoers instead of the above:

```
Defaults env_keep += "BORG_* !BORG_CACHE_DIR !BORG_SECURITY_DIR"
```

However, this still didn't exclude the two variables I'm trying to exclude from the wildcard expression.

A simpler usage of the `-=` and `+=` operators, without wildcards, does work as expected, as in the following:

```
Defaults env_keep += "BORG_REPO BORG_LOGGING_CONF BORG_CONFIG_DIR BORG_CACHE_DIR"
Defaults env_keep -= "BORG_CACHE_DIR"
```

So perhaps it's just a limitation of how wildcards in sudoers are parsed: the `-=` lines are discarded as irrelevant before the `*` is expanded to the full set of variables it matches.

Comment: I wonder if the issue is that `*` doesn't actually get expanded to a list of matching variables? Perhaps you could try the *disable* (`!`) rather than the *delete from* (`-=`) operator?

Comment: @steeldriver  Certainly the BORG_* line does get expanded and add the relevant variables to the environment, as confirmed by running `sudo env | grep BORG` with and without the line. Using the `!` operator was a good thought, but didn't pan out in my attempt -- see my edit, I'm happy to try another form if you have a different suggestion.

Comment: If we assume the list is tested in the order given, perhaps this might work:
`env_keep += "!BORG_CACHE_DIR !BORG_SECURITY_DIR BORG_*"`

Comment: @meuh  An interesting idea, but did not work -- all BORG variables were still added as if the `!` entries weren't there. My reading of the man page is that `!`, in the context of Defaults entries, could be used to disable the whole env_keep facility, but not to negate individual list entries. For wildcards in env_keep, the man page says we get `*`, which matches 0 or more chars, and that's it.